# How to defer loading of twitter's bootstrap's remote modal content?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, monkeypatching

I want use bootstrap's auto-magic remote content loading via ajax in my modals, but this seems to fetch the contents at the precise moment the modal is instantiated ( [source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js) )

There's no way to simply [duck-punch](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) the Modal constructor is there, seeing as it's module-wrapped and all? I would like for a placeholder content within the .modal-body to be overridden by the ajax loaded contents but only when modal is first triggered into view.

Comment: I've resolved my original issue by taking an entirely different approahc, but I'm still curious to know if we can in fact override bootstrap's internal module constructors and prototypes.

Comment: Perhaps you could detail your "alternative approach"? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Dominic, it wont help you. I didn't say "alternative approach" but in fact "entirely different approach" meaning that I changed the way my app works so I didn't have to do this.

Comment: Ahh damn. I think i might hook into the "show" event on modals

Comment: you could hook a once-off "shown" on each "show" event to act as a "aftershow" using $(element).one('event', fn ) maybe?